# What is wrong with this computation of the fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to compute the fundamental group of $\{x : \|x\| < 1\}$. It should be trivial as I can contract to one point. What is wrong with the following method?

Consider the map $H(x, t) = (1 - t)x + tx/(2\|x\|)$. We claim that $H$ is a deformation retraction of $X = \{x : \|x\| < 1\}$ onto $A = \{x : \|x\| = 1/2\}$. We have $H(x, 0) = x$ and $H(x, 1) \in A$ for all $x \in X$ and $H(a, t) = a$ for all $a \in A$. Since $A$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$, it follows that $\pi_{1}(X) = \mathbb{Z}$. What is wrong with this proof?

Answer (score 3):

Your retraction is not defined at $x=(0,0)$. If you had considered the punctured disk there would be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is ill-defined, e.g. since you have

$$ H(\vec{0},1) = \vec{0} / 0$$

and there is no way to continuously extend $H$ to fill things in.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the map $x \mapsto x/||x||$ is not well defined in $0$.